# Javascript run onChange not onLoad

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple piece of Javascript that works perfectly `onLoad`, but I need it to work `onChange`.

My script;

```
<form action="" method="post" name="product_search">
    <p><strong>Existing Part Number:</strong>
      <input name="v_prodref" type="text" id="v_prodref" size="25" maxlength="25" onChange="searchValue()"> 
      <input type="text" name="prodref" id="prodref">

      <input type="submit" name="search_Submit" id="search_Submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
    <div>
    <%=(rs_ProductCheck.Fields.Item("prodref").Value)%>
    // <%=(rs_ProductCheck.Fields.Item("proddesc").Value)%></div>
    <script>
        function searchValue() {
        var add = "NW";
        var c_ProdRef = document.getElementById('v_prodref');
        if(c_ProdRef.search(/GST/i) == -1) {
        n_ProdRef = c_ProdRef.concat(add) }
        else {
        n_ProdRef = c_ProdRef.replace(/GST/i,"NWGST") }
        document.getElementById("prodref").value = n_ProdRef;
        }
        </script> 
    </form>
```

So, I enter a part number in the first text box, and I want my javascript to run and enter the new value in the second text box, but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to debug step by step, in the `searchValue`, what is not working

Comment: when you say it doesnt work, what are the steps that you tried that led you to the conclusion that it doesnt work? cause the `searchValue()` function is hit here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/348/

Comment: the new value is not showing up in the prodref text field.

Comment: @indubitablee: You'll note that your fiddle throws an exception, so there's a hint.

Comment: thats becase `c_ProdRef.search is not a function` you have an error in your code that isnt attributed to `onchange`. you would have seen that `onload` as well

Comment: @DavidHedlund a change from `onload` to `onchange` wouldnt cause this error. OP stated that "it worked perfectly" `onload` to which i would assume that he has no errors on his side with the functionality of his javascript, only the trigger

Comment: This is the code which works fine `onLoad`, `<script>
 var add = "NW";
var c_ProdRef = "<%=Request.QueryString("prodref")%>";
if(c_ProdRef.search(/GST/i) == -1) {
    n_ProdRef = c_ProdRef.concat(add) }
else {
    n_ProdRef = c_ProdRef.replace(/GST/i,"NWGST") }
document.getElementById("new_prodref").value = n_ProdRef;
</script>` What I am trying to change is the `c_ProdRef` value is entered from a user, not recordset.

Answer (score 0):

`search` does not exist on an `HTMLInputElement`. You need to use `c_ProdRef.value.search`.

(Actually, since you're using it in many places as a string, and never as an input, you probably intended to define `c_ProdRef` as var `document.getElementById('v_prodref').value`)

You would've seen this error on load as well.

Comment: searchValue() is the name of my function which I am calling?

Comment: @JonathanGriffin: Yes, but you're calling `c_ProdRef.search(/GST/i)` and there is no `search` on an `HTMLInputElement`. You probably intended for `c_ProdRef` to be a string, in which case it should be assigned as `document.getElementById('v_prodref').value`, where you've missed the `.value` bit.

Comment: In the comment you've added to the question, the value of `c_ProdRef` is indeed a string, `var c_ProdRef = "<%=Request.QueryString("prodref")%>"`, but in your modified code, it is a form element, when you intended to access the *value* of that form element.

Answer (score 0):

you want `onkeyup` if it works perfectly `onLoad`, and you want to start typing in something in textbox 1 and the javascript to run, you dont want `onchange`

`onchange` triggers after blur of focused element

`onkeyup` triggers after you release a keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their help. After a little tweaking I have managed to get my code working.

```
function myFunction() {
    var add = "NW";
    var c_ProdRef = document.getElementById('v_prodref').value;
    if (c_ProdRef.search(/GST/i) == -1) {
        n_ProdRef = c_ProdRef.concat(add)
    } else {
        n_ProdRef = c_ProdRef.replace(/GST/i, "NWGST")
    }
    document.getElementById("prodref").value = n_ProdRef;
}
```

Along with @indubitablee suggestion of `onKeyup` and specifying the `.value` of my first text field it all works.